# "\xc2:\xc2" in HTTP proxy GET request

Tags: logging, http, url

Recently I came across lines like these in an HTTP server's access_log (I've changed the real image to "someimage.jpg" - you can browse the images folder directly since directory listing is allowed, in case you want to try with a real image):

```
GET http://www.hindu.com\xc2:\xc2/mp/2006/07/03/images/someimage.jpg HTTP/1.1" 400 313 "-" "webcollage/1.135a
```

The user agent seems to be [webcollage](http://linux.die.net/man/6/webcollage), which is a tool to decorate the screen with random images from the web - but I guess it is faked. Obviously it was tried to use the HTTP server as HTTP proxy.

Now what I wonder about is the `\xc2:\xc2` part in the URL. Without that part it would be a valid URL. With that string the first `\xc2` would be interpreted as part of the top level domain, while the second one would be interpreted as port.
It didn't find any reference to a vulnerability connected to that string, but a lot of access logs via Google containing similar lines, without any explanation.

Any ideas what was tried here?